# Доступ к папке в android

Tags: android, gallery

Доброго всем времени суток. Вопрос не обычен, как по мне ;) Есть папка в корне приложения, создаем программно и сохраняем туда фото с камеры. Ситуация такая - нужно, чтобы доступа к папке из вне не было, т.е. папка приватная, и это уже сделано, но в то же самое время требуют, чтобы папка была видна в галерее. Есть ли решения для таких ситуаций?

Comment: Думаю, нет. Делегировать права доступа между приложениями вроде бы нельзя.

Comment: @Чад, спасибо. Придется как-то иначе решать вопрос...

Comment: Можно написать свою галерею:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, не совсем все безнадежно. Здесь есть маленькая деталька: дело в том, что в галерее хранятся иконки изображений, при клике на которые виджет вытаскивает картинку с оригинального местоположения картинки.

То есть можно попробовать обмануть систему, подсунув ей иконку (thumbnail) картинки, но не давать саму картинку (или еще хитрее - дать ей стуб картинки).

Вся эта байда с thumbnail картинки управляется `MediaScanner` - посмотрите на него. Я думаю, что если постараться, то можно что-нибудь изобразить с этим.

В итоге (если получится) будет такая картинка: юзер будет видеть в галерее иконки ваших приватных картинок, но не сможет видеть их оригиналы, ну или вместо оригинала будет видеть фигу - какой-нибудь stub.

Comment: Хорошая идея!

Comment: @Nuclominus так получилось или нет? Самому любопытно

Comment: Решилось тем, что создал аналогичную папку в галерее и копировал туда фото)